# Python: tying a bunch of lists together (like Excel columns)

Tags: python

I’m used to Excel, so I’m having difficulty thinking about how to do something like this in Python (it doesn’t help that I’m new to coding). In Excel, I’d have one column of numbers, one of letters, one of categories, and could easily get what I’m looking for. I’ve tried searching for how to ‘tie’ lists in the way that columns are linked in Excel, but I think my terminology/mindset is off.

I have two lists, each element ‘links’ to the other, e.g. a = 2:

```
[a, b, c, d]
[2, 7, 5, 6]
```

I have another set of lists in another file, categories.txt:

```
[‘a’, ‘color’, ‘blue’]
[‘b’, ‘color’, ‘green’]
[‘c’, ‘fruit’, ‘apple’]
[‘d’, ‘color’, ‘blue’]
```

I want to somehow tie all this information together into a format where I can ask for color or blue and get the number, maybe another set of lists like:

output (?):

```
[color, blue, 8]   #‘a’ and ‘d’ are added to get 8, since they’re both blue
[color, green, 7]
[fruit, apple, 5]
```

If it matters for the output formatting, this is eventually going to be sent over to R so I can visualize how many blue I have within the color category (8), how many green (7), etc. Will some form of a dictionary work maybe? I've read the documentation and the O'Reilly book sections for dictionaries but they don't seem quite right.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one option for you. You can create an object that holds all of the information for you. You can use a list as I did or even label each attribute that you pass in and only check for one of them.

```
class ColourGroup:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def has_item(self, item):
        if item in self.data:
            return True
        else:
            return False

colour_groups = [        
    ColourGroup([2, 'a', 'color', 'blue']),
    ColourGroup([7, 'b', 'color', 'green']),
    ColourGroup([5, 'c', 'fruit', 'apple']),
    ColourGroup([6, 'd', 'color', 'blue']),
]

def get_colour_group(colour_groups, option):
    return_groups = []
    for colour_group in colour_groups:
        if colour_group.has_item(option):
            return_groups.append(colour_group.data)
    return return_groups

print(get_colour_group(colour_groups, 'blue'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get a dict that ties lists `[a, b, c, d]` and
`[2, 7, 5, 6]` together using `zip()`:

```
alpha_list = [a, b, c, d]
num_list = [2, 7, 5, 6]

lookup_dict = dict(zip(alpha_list, num_list))
```

Now, let's say your list of lists is stored as below (assuming you have the piece of code to parse your file into the list of lists):

```
from collections import defaultdict

category_lists = [[‘a’, ‘color’, ‘blue’], [‘b’, ‘color’, ‘green’], [‘c’, ‘fruit’, ‘apple’], [‘d’, ‘color’, ‘blue’]]

# Lookup the relevant number (from the above dict) for each category list 
# Sum up according to category + color (eg. 'color blue')
# The below builds up a dictionary like this (for the sample data):
# { 'color blue': 8,
#   'color green': 7,
#   'fruit apple': 5
# }
# where from the code, the key into our dict is category_list[1]+' '+category_list[2] 
# eg. 'color blue'
# and the alphabet code at category_list[0] is looked up using the dict above 
# and added to the running total for 'color blue'

my_groups = defaultdict(int)
for category_list in category_lists:
    my_groups[category_list[1]+' '+category_list[2]] += lookup_dict[category_list[0]]

# To view your output:
for key in my_groups:
    out_list = key.split(' ')
    out_list.append(my_groups[key])
    print out_list
```

Comment: Could you break down a little more what this is doing?: for category_list in category_lists:
    my_groups[category_list[1]+' '+category_list[2]] += lookup_dict[category_list[0]]

Comment: This doesn't work as written. Error is on line my_groups = defaultdict(int), it gives a syntax error

Comment: Did you add the import statement?

Comment: 'from collections import defaultdict'? yep!